# How to Convert Ruby string to a C++ char pointer

Tags: c++, ruby

I trying to call a Win32Api dll function in Ruby:

```
LoadTexture = Win32API.new('System/SFML.dll', 'sfml_load_texture', 'p', 'p')
```

My code calling:

```
LoadTexture.call("folder/file.png")
```

My second try to convert data (just work with wchar_t)

```
  buf = ''

  for i in 0..filename.size - 1
    buf += filename[i] + 0.chr
  end

  buf += 0.chr * 260

  LoadTexture.call(buf)
```

DLL function
[image]

I get

> Failed to load image "=»`¶È;      ð¿w  c  H ". Reason: Unable to open

Comment: Please post error messages as text not grey on black images.

Answer (score 1):

sfml has a ruby binding. The sfml project links to the ruby binding: https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/bindings.php. Loading textures appears to be supported by the binding.